# Unable to check if variable is empty in views twig

Tags: views, theming

I am trying to overwrite `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` file and want to check if **title** variable **is empty** or not, but whatever I do, it always acts just like it is **not empty**.

I know title variable is an object, I tried dpm() it but no modifiers work in checking if it is empty.

My code:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{{ dpm(title) }}
{% if title|render|trim|length is not empty %}

{% set row_id = 1 %}

{% for key, row in rows %}
    {% set row_id = key+1 %}
{% endfor %}
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-{{ row_id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-{{ row_id }}">
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse-{{ row_id }}">
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row views-row-' ~ loop.index
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
{% if title|render|trim|length is not empty %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_capture is related.

Answer (score 1):

`{% if title|render|striptags|trim %}` should work.

1. `title|render` to render, i.e. convert from render array to html string.
2. `|striptags` to remove any html tags from the rendered title.
3. `|trim` to remove any whitespace from beginning and end.

If `title` is already an html string (i.e. not a render array) then you can omit `|render` and `{% if title|striptags|trim %}` should be good enough.

Comment: Though you do need to use `|length` if your title can literally be the string "0". See [twig if docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/if.html) for other twig bool edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so It looks like this works:

```
{% if title|trim|spaceless|striptags|length != 0 %}
```

Which looks incredibly stupid but well...